# copying array to a new one with memcpy

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I have an issue where i'm using `memcpy()` to copy an array to a new array with dynamic memory. And my question is why there is 3 zeros between the numbers? like my original array is `a1[] ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` and when I use `memcpy(mem1,a1,n1)` then my mem1 will be `1 0 0 0 2` ?
Here's my code:

```
int join_arrays(unsigned int n1, int *a1, unsigned int n2, int *a2, unsigned 
int n3, int *a3)
{
    /*Here I just print the original a1 just to make sure it's correct*/
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        printf("%d  ", a1[j]);
    }
    /*I allocate the memory for the new array*/
    char *mem1;
    mem1 = malloc(n1*sizeof(int));

    /*checking if the allocation succeeded*/
    if (!mem1) {
    printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
    exit(-1);
    }

    /*Using memcpy() to copy the original array to the new one*/
    memcpy(mem1, a1, n1);

    /*Printing the new array and this print gives me "1 0 0 0 2"
      and it should give me "1 2 3 4 5"*/
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d  ", mem1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(void)
{
    /* these are the original arrays which I need to put together to a single array */
    int a1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int a2[] = { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 };
    int a3[] = { 20, 21, 22 };

    /*The number of elements are before the array itself*/
    join_arrays(5, a1, 8, a2, 3, a3);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of allocating the memory and assigning it to `char*` take a `int*` and work with it.

```
int *mem1;
mem1 = malloc(n1*sizeof(int)); // malloc(n1 * sizeof *mem1);
..
memcpy(mem1,a1,n1*sizeof(a1[0]));
```

Also check whether malloc failed or not - but add a proper error message:-

```
if (!mem1) {
   perror("Memory allocation failed\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Don't forget to free the dynamically allocated memory, in your case

```
free(mem1);
```

As you have said, that you need to return it from the function then you would do something like this

```
int *join_arrays(..){

  return mem1;
}
int main(void){

  int *p = join_arrays(..);
  /* work with it */

  free(p);
}
```

Comment: This worked thanks, but my function have to return a pointer to that new array mem1 so do I have to free the memory still?

Comment: @michael.: Will add this to answer..wait.

Comment: @michael.: Edited.

Comment: Okay yea that's what I thought!

Answer (score 1):

`mem1` here is a char pointer not an int pointer.

Therefore when you try to print `mem1[i]` it will actually print the byte that is stored at address `mem1+i` instead of 4 bytes. Apparently the integer `1` is stored like this on your machine :

```
 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

that is why you get 3 zeros.

Try changing your variable type to `int*` like this :

```
int *mem1;
mem1 = malloc(n1*sizeof(int));
memcpy(mem1,a1,n1*sizeof(int));
```